# Azure timer trigger function is not executing script log at all

Tags: azure-functions

I was testing timer trigger function with testing template and cannot execute the script and any logs as 'JavaScript timer trigger function ran!'. It was working for me before, but then for the next day it simply does not execute the script the function itself seems running but I cannot test the script and do not understand what is the issue.
My function.js file

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "myTimer",
      "type": "timerTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "schedule": "0 * * * * *",
      "runOnStartup": true
    }
  ]
}
```

local.settings.json

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "node",
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "githubKey": "sample123"
  },
  "Host": {
    "LocalHttpPort": 7071,
    "CORS": "*",
    "CORSCredentials": false
  }
}
```

This is what I have in my terminal

[image]

index.js

```
 module.exports = async function (context, myTimer) {
    var timeStamp = new Date().toISOString();

    if (myTimer.IsPastDue)
    {
        context.log('JavaScript is running late!');
    }
    context.log('JavaScript timer trigger function ran!', timeStamp);   
};
```

Comment: It is no problems on my side.

Comment: Can you recreated a function and test again. It seems no problem.

Comment: Can you show the .js file part of your function(the javascript)? And please notice that function and local.settings is .json not js.

Comment: put your sample code in github, it would be easy to check.

Comment: @BowmanZhu u mean index.js it is default script code, but i will put

Comment: @BowmanZhu but I dont see any logs as JavaScript timer trigger function ran!. It is strange terminal should log to me right?

Comment: Yes, your code seems no problem. Maybe the Storage Account is used by other webjobs or other env. Try a different Storage Account and try again.

Comment: I noticed that your function name is Merge Trigger in your screenshot, does this have any special meaning? You set runOnStartup to true, theoretically it will be executed immediately once anyway.

Comment: I notice you are using `UseDevelopmentStorage=true`, so did you start your storage emulator client local?

Comment: @GeorgeChen yes I am using azurite amulator

Comment: @BowmanZhu sorry do I need to create storage account for testing environment. I dont wanna store anything or I need to create it in order to make script run?

Answer (score -1):

I could reproduce your problem, then I find the same issue in the github:[Improve Timer trigger behavior with host lock](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-core-tools/issues/55).

[image]

It's caused by Singleton Lock, more details you could refer to this:[Singleton Locks](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-extensions/wiki/TimerTrigger#singleton-locks), and under the Local Development it say:

> The default for ListenerLockPeriod is 60 seconds, which means that if
>   the host is killed ungracefully (e.g. the Console window is shut when
>   running locally) the blob lease that was held cannot be reacquired
>   until the lease naturally expires. This means that if you kill a
>   running instance then attempt to immediately restart the JobHost,
>   you'll see that the function won't start running immediately since
>   it's waiting to acquire the Singleton lock.

Suppose this is the reason for your problem, so in the github issue there is a [solution](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-core-tools/issues/55#issuecomment-289978924), set the `listenerLockPeriod` in the host.json.

Here is a sample:

```
"singleton": {
    "listenerLockPeriod": "00:00:15" 
  }
```

[image]

Comment: sorry, but I still dont see the logs while running the function :(((

Comment: What if you change the value smaller like 5, and if the `listenLockPeriod` changed in the stack log also if your log changed show the next 5 run time?

Comment: Sorry, I dont fully get, but u mean to change listenLockPeriod from 15 to 5? @GeorgeChen

Comment: Yes, maybe you could have a try and don't start function immediately.

Comment: I am having this error after change

"A host error has occurred during startup operation '54405405-d786-41e5-b4da-e225a6baa111'.
 System.Private.CoreLib: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
Parameter name: value."

Comment: Sorry for that, I check the wiki looks like the minimum value is 15 seconds.